# How to make Amazon Polly speak very loud?

Tags: amazon-polly

I am trying to use Polly for a customer ticket calling application in Brazilian Portuguese using Camila Neural voice.

https://console.aws.amazon.com/polly/home/SynthesizeSpeech?region=us-east-1

```
<speak>
<prosody volume="x-loud">
Senha comum 
<break time="100ms"/>10
</prosody>
</speak>
```

But using `<prosody volume="x-loud">` seems to have none or very little effect.

Maxing out the volume on the TV for ticket calling outputs and inaudible sound because of the environment (It's close to the street, so there's urban noise).

How do I produce a "stronger"/louder speak?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/supportedtags.html#drc-tag

Dynamic Range Compression does the trick.